# Why do I receive this MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'first_name' cannot be null when exuting this script?

Tags: mysql, jsp, jdbc, forms, http-post

I'm trying to insert html-form data into my database using the script below but when running the app I receive this error message:

> Error..com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException:
>   Column 'first_name' cannot be null

What am I doing wrong? `:/`

```
  <%
        Connection con = null;  
        PreparedStatement st = null;

        String first_name = request.getParameter("first_name");
        String last_name = request.getParameter("last_name");
        String phone = request.getParameter("phone");
        String email = request.getParameter("email");
        String address_1 = request.getParameter("address_1");
        String address_2 = request.getParameter("address_2");
        String city = request.getParameter("city");
        String State_Province_Region = request.getParameter("State_Province_Region");
        String Postal_Zip_Code = request.getParameter("Postal_Zip_Code");
        String country = request.getParameter("Country");


        try {
              con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/application","root",
         "password");

              st = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO customer (first_name, last_name, phone, email, address_1, address_2, city, State_Province_Region, Postal_Zip_Code, Country) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");


                 st.setString(1,first_name);
                 st.setString(2,last_name);
                 st.setString(3,phone);

                 st.setString(4,email);
                 st.setString(5,address_1);
                 st.setString(6,address_2);

                 st.setString(7,city);
                 st.setString(8,State_Province_Region);
                 st.setString(9,Postal_Zip_Code);

                 st.setString(10,country);

              st.executeUpdate();
              st.clearParameters(); 



             st.close();
             con.close();
        } 

        catch (Exception e) { 
             out.println("Error.."+e);
        }
%>
```

Comment: Can we see the URL you are sending to the server?  Better yet, check it yourself.  I'll bet 1000 Stack Overflow points that you are passing in a `null` value.

Answer (score 1):

I know this sounds obvious... but you have the setting for the firstname column in the database set to not allow null values.  Also, you must be passing in a null value for that field in one of the rows.

Perhaps, put a breakpoint in there to catch what the actual sql command is after the request variables are filled.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting `System.out.println()` statements and debug what values are coming for `first_name, last_name` etc...

Other Wrong things:
1 Move all the JDBC code to a separate Java file 
2 close() statements should be in the finally block. They wouldn't have executed in your case when there are exceptions.